# toggle doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I don't know why this code of mine doesn't work... I want the "+" sign to be shown up and when we click on that sign then to be "-" and at the same time the paragraph be shown up. When we click the "-" sign to return in the initial state.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main").append("<img src='https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/plus-sign-10.png' id='clickMe' />");
  $("#message").hide();

  $("#clickMe").toggle(function() {
      $("#clickMe").attr("src", "https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/minus-sign-10.png");
      $("#message").show();
    },
    function() {
      $("#clickMe").attr("src", "https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/plus-sign-10.png");
      $("#message").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
<p id="message">You should see this message!</p>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, toggle does not have 2 functions http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are ever firing the toggle event that you set up listeners for..

Comment: @Huangism It was available at one point, however, it was depricated as of v1.8 and removed as of v1.9 https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ -- I just realized he's on 2.2.0, so that is very likely the issue

Comment: So it makes sense for this not to work since OP is using 2.2

Comment: Not entirely sure why they removed that, but it is what it is.. Either way, @Danis35 is going to need to need an event handler that triggers .toggle(), and need to update the toggle function to contain control structures for show/hide

Comment: Yes, you are all of you right. I wonder why every time something is changed even before you completely understand it :) Fortunately, @Jonathan.Brink give me the concept of what u've said and finally with the click event solution (not using toggle() function at all - I could have named the function "toggle_1" for example) and a few corrections of his snippet, I made it. Thank u all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ribopupelo/edit?html,js,output).

jQuery's [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function doesn't handle the click event...you need to use `click()` for that.

```
var $clickMe = $("#clickMe"),
    $message = $("#message");

function toggle() {
    if ($message.is(':visible')) {
        $clickMe.attr("src","https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/plus-sign-10.png");
        $message.hide();
    } else {
        $clickMe.attr("src","https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/minus-sign-10.png");
        $message.show();
    }
}

$clickMe.click(function(){
    toggle();
});
```

Comment: The fiddle code is a little mess in combination with this snippet here... it doesn't work... but...but!!! it helped me a lot!!! Thank u very much Jonathan!  I found the solution:

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#main").append("<img src='https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/plus-sign-10.png' id='clickMe' />");
$("#message").hide();

function toggle() {
  if ($("#message").is(':visible')) {
    $("#clickMe").attr("src", "https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/plus-sign-10.png");
    $("#message").hide();
  } else {
    $("#clickMe").attr("src", "https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/graphics/ui/minus-sign-10.png");
    $("#message").show();
  }
}

$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  toggle();
});
```

It works!